# Websockify error "Client must support 'binary' or 'base64' protocol"

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to use websockify to allow javascript executed in a browser to talk to my hand-written server. When using the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, I get the following error message from websockify:
    Client must support 'binary' or 'base64' protocol

After looking at the code, I've determined that websockify delivers this message and closes the socket whenever both of these protocols fail to appear under the Sec-Websocket-Protocol header received from the client. When I look at the raw data transmitted by Chrome it doesn't even send this header. Is this a problem with Chrome or websockify, or am I failing to provide some information when opening the websocket in my javascript? Or is there some other explanation?

Comment: After doing some further reading I upgraded the connection to a secure websocket(In case some headers were being dropped along the way.) Initially chrome was causing a different error but after forcing chrome to accept my self-signed certificate I'm still at square one in both firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to provide the protocol list as part of the object constructor:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(uri, ['binary', 'base64']);
```

If you use the websock.js library included with websockify then it will handle this for you. However, note that websock.js does not provide the standard WebSocket API but rather a streaming oriented API. Even if you use a raw WebSocket connection to websockify, note that you will still need to do message reconstruction because normal TCP does not have a concept of messages so the messages chunking from onmessage will be essentially "arbitrary".

Comment: Thank you so much. Apparently hours of research failed to lead me to either of those vital two pieces of information.

Comment: The documentation (on MDN and webplatform.org) doesn't mention this at all.

Comment: @CpnCrunch, the second argument to the constructor is either a single string indicating the sub-protocol or an array of sub-protocols in preference order. The 'binary' and 'base64' values are specific to websockify. See the W3C definition of the WebSocket interface: http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/#the-websocket-interface

Comment: Yes, the w3c site is the only place that gives proper definitions for all the websocket (and other html5) stuff. Unfortunately it is incredibly badly written and difficult to quickly find what you're looking for. The other sites are much easier to use, but they leave out half the information. Anyway, thanks for websockify - it works very well.

Comment: @CpnCrunch, the W3C site I referenced isn't badly written, it's just written for browser creators and not web developers. The specific part of the page I linked to is the WebIDL definition which is a precise machine readable definition of the interface that can be used to automatically generate the API code and verification tests, etc. That's the REAL definition, everything else is a paraphrase. That being said, the webplatform page could use improvement. It's a wiki, I authorize you to improve it. :-)

Comment: This error is also thrown when using the websocket.org echo test http://www.websocket.org/echo.html I presume due to it using "default" websocket implementations.  Interesting that they don't provide an option to change the socket mode given this tidbit of information.